# menu is not working properly in IE8/7

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am haveing issues with menu in IE7/8.. when i hover over the navigation.. the submenu is also showing in the list of main menu ..

please check the second menu in IE8

http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/ and give me some fix ..

please help me guys

Comment: Give more info, do you create the menu yourself? Use a library ?...

Comment: yes .. i create myself and using jquery library ... superfish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not positioning your submenu at all. Try this:

```
nav#primary-menu ul#menu-mainnav li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @MuzammilHussain thats awesome, if the answer satisfied your question please approve it to close this thread.